# Aframe Physics component: bounce along a path

Tags: aframe, cannon.js

I am using Don Mccurdy's physics engine and able to set the dynamic body and static body to bounce a sphere. I wish the ball to bounce along a path. What should be the approach I take in writing some animation code? And in case there is some reference code that will greatly help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to bounce the path in some direction, you can simply apply an impulse which will steer the ball.

```
let body // refers to the aframes entity.body
body.applyImpulse(
/* impulse vector*/        new CANNON.Vec3(x, y, z),
/* world position vector*/ new CANNON.Vec3(x, y, z)
);
```

Check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8cr6hmay/2/).

---

However if you want the ball to bounce with a complex path, then you should disable the physics engine (remove the `dynamic-body`) and use the [animation-timeline](https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/animation-timeline/) component.

Comment: Thanks @milewski. Currently, using something like this. I use the `vector`. Interesting that you mention `animation-timeline`, I did think about that but since I was hoping to use the physics component, the obvious challenge is when to apply the next stage of the animation?

Is there any event that is triggered at the end of say a physics movement?